# Mythbuntu using a HVR-1600 and most of the channels are just garbage. How to fix?

Tags: mythbuntu

I recently installed Mythbuntu on an old HP box with a HVR-1600.  I have installed the new drivers and firmware from linuxtv (cx18) and everything seems to be working.  Only the local channels are working through the HVR-1600.  From Schedules Direct my channels line up with INC Group through my university.

From what I read, INC is supposed to not need a cable box and be able to use on any cable ready tv (which is true with a direct coax input into my tv).  How do I get my these additional channels through my tuner card?  Are the other channels encrypted?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!